# SlideToggle closes when Filter is chosen

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle

**Info:**

I've added a button on my homepage, which triggers a div to expand. The div shows 3 different filters, which you can choose.

**The problem is:**

After choosing the first filter, the div closes again. To choose the 2nd and 3rd filter, you got to press the button again to expand the div. And the problem happens again when clicking on the 2nd filter.

**Question:**

How can I prevent closing of my div, while choosing filters?

**My code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if($(window).width()<768) $("#button-opl").on('click',function(){
        $("#views-exposed-form-attraktioner-block").slideToggle();  
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Need more info on this? Where is your code related to filters? That is where problem is.

Comment: Its a modul I use in Drupal. Its set to automatically refresh the filter. but I need to have it on auto.

Comment: So you are saying, that whenever you click filter, page gets refreshed?

Comment: The page doesnt get refreshed. Its a block or div on the page which gets refreshed.

Comment: Then I would say, question can't be answered with this much of information. Please try to add some more info on this.

Comment: Please post your HTML and rest of jquery code. I believe that the event is being propagated when he clicks on the filter as well.

Comment: Can you confirm if your filter also has a click event registered on it?

Comment: Yes it has a click event on it, but its hidden and set to automatically. When visiting the webpage from PC i want it to be in automatically and when visit from mobile or tablet, I want it still to be automatically, but here I have the filters hidden. The filters are showen when clicked on the button.